Questions about merkle tree for eventual consistency
I'm currently implementing offline support for an app of mine. I stumbled upon merkle trees, to ensure eventual consistency and I understand the general concept. I also stumbled upon this implementation in the actualbudget repo. But there are still a couple things I don't understand, which stop me from implementing my own solution.
This is what I understand:

I track any operations in the leaf nodes and group them by a fixed time interval. The implementation above seems to use intervals of one minute.
I diff the merkle trees to find inconsistencies.
At some point I prune the tree and get rid of old data. That will cause clients that haven't connected in a long time to lose the ability to sync, meaning they'll have to do a full reset and use their unsaved changes.

What I'm still missing:

Even though I'm grouping the operations in buckets, the hash tree might still quickly become incredibly large, won't it? Let's say people work ~60 minutes in my app per day. That's 60 leaf nodes a day. If I want to store data for the past 6 months, that's ~180 days, resulting in 10800 leaf nodes. Is there something else that's used to keep the number of leaf nodes small?
Assuming that I track every operation that happens, the list of operations will also quickly grow very large. That will (a) make my db on the server grow very large and (b) will force me to send a lot of data when doing a full sync with a client. In the example above, each leaf bucket would likely contain more than one operation, so if I have to do a full sync, I'll send multiples of 10k database entries. Any tricks here?
How does pruning work? The implementation above seems to prune some nodes after every operation. I still don't understand that, though. To me it seems like the implementation doesn't use a rolling window for hash tree keys (meaning the keys are not relative in time, but absolute). Won't it prune the same keys over and over then? My assumption was that we always prune the last N months or something like that!?

Would really appreciate if someone could shed some light on how a concrete implementation would work.
